# In java JMonkeyEngine, public GameSettings getNewSettings()? How do I fill it out?

Tags: java, 3d, java-3d, jmonkeyengine

I'm trying to change a BaseGame to a FixedFrameRateGame, and It's saying I need a public GameSettings getNewSettings() method. Now I tried filling out like this:

```
public GameSettings getNewSettings(){
        return null;
    }
```

it gives me a nullpointerexception when I try to run it.

Comment: The jMonkey developers don't frequent StackOverflow much. I suggest you visit the forum at jmonkeyengine.org and restate your query there.

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked with JMonkeyEngine before, but you probably need to create an object that implements the GameSettings interface, in your class, and have it be initialized somewhere on the constructor of an object of that class.

In order for you to know what methods and functions the object you create that implements GameSettings interface will have to implement you can check the [JMonkeyEngine API](http://www.jmonkeyengine.com/doc/)

Hope that helps.